# $\|A\|^2=\|A^* A\|$ for linear bounded operators on hilbert space?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I'm reading some functional analysis notes and the author use the fact that for bounded linear operator $A$ on Hilbert space holds $\|A\|^2=\|A^*A\|$.
I know that holds $\|A^*A\|\leq\|A^*\|\|A\|=\|A\|\|A\|$ but I'm having difficulties proving the other inequality.
I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: See the approved answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459696/norm-of-a-2-times-2-matrix-as-a-hilbert-space-operator?noredirect=1

Comment: The other inequality is easy : $\|A^*A\|\ge \sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle =\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\|A\|^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $A^*A$ is self-adjoint
$$
\|A^*A\|=\sup_{\|u\|=1}|(A^*Au,u)|=\sup_{\|u\|=1}|(Au,Au)|=\sup_{\|u\|=1}\|Au\|^2=\|A\|^2
$$